# Enabling and disabling of a field not working inside javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to enable and disable one picklist field based on another picklist field. Here is the piece of code through which i am trying to achieve that

```
<script>
    function Compchange(){
        alert('Hello');
      document.getElementById('{!$Component.CompLostTo}').disabled = false;
    }
</script>

                <apex:inputField value="{!closeOppObj.Competitor__c}" onchange="Compchange();"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!closeOppObj.Competitor_Lost_To__c}" id="CompLostTo" /> 
                <script>document.getElementById('{!$Component.CompLostTo}').disabled = true; </script>
```

i am facing issue with the document.getElementById('{!$Component.CompLostTo}').disabled = false; syntax which is inside the function Compchange(), is it not working as expected. Please suggest how to resolve .. any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) attribute, all that matters is it's presence or absence; the specific value doesn't matter. You can get rid of it with the [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) function.

Also, judging by the indentation in your question, it looks like your function might be at a different level in the hierarchy and you need to reference the component with the id path for `$Component` to get the DOM id.

```
<script>
    function Compchange(){
       document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.thePageBlock.CompLostTo}').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
</script>
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock" >
                <apex:inputField value="{!closeOppObj.Competitor__c}" onchange="Compchange();"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!closeOppObj.Competitor_Lost_To__c}" id="CompLostTo" /> 
                <script>document.getElementById('{!$Component.CompLostTo}').disabled = true; </script>
```

Comment: Tried doing the same but still facing the same issue. Also i can see that the alert statement inside the function is working fine, only issue is happening with removeattribute syntax.